# How to Get All the Values from a ASP gridview footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been fighting this problem all day.  I have a `asp:Gridview` with several footer Templates that has several TextBox fields, a DropDown and a CheckBox. I hide the footer until the add records `asp:button` is clicked. That all works and I can enter data in the text boxes, chose elections from the drop down and cycle the checkbox. Now when I try to save the data to the database I use this code.

```
protected void MembersGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("EmptyInsert"))
    {

    }

    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
    {

        int Role =Convert.ToInt32((MembersGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlRole") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value);
        string FirstName = (MembersGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox).Text;
        string LastName = (MembersGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox).Text;
        TextBox UserName = MembersGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUserName") as TextBox;
        TextBox Email = MembersGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox;
        CheckBox active = MembersGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("chkActive") as CheckBox;
        DbContext.AAHMembersAdd(Role, FirstName, LastName, UserName.Text, Email.Text, active.Checked);

        //MembersGridView.EditIndex = -1;

        MembersGridView.DataSource = DbContext.VW_Members.ToList(); 
        DataBind();
    }
}

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" ItemStyle-Width="100">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("firstname")%>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("firstname")%>'></asp:TextBox>
   </EditItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have added the aspx for one of the Template fields all are the same as this one except the drop down and CheckBox

The DropDown and the CheckBox data is returned however all of my TextBox values are returned as an empty string. What am I missing here. As you can see I have already tries a couple of different ways but the results are the same.

Comment: Can you post your .aspx?

Comment: <FooterTemplate>
                           <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                       </FooterTemplate> this is what the aspx looks like for the footer template @-w0051977

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see; you are not setting the text to anything - therefore the textbox.text value is an empty string.  Try changing this code:

```
<FooterTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </FooterTemplate>
```

to this:

```
<FooterTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" text="hello" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </FooterTemplate>
```

also change this:

```
string FirstName = (MembersGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox).Text;
```

to this:

```
 string FirstName = (MembersGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox).Text;
```

Comment: The first change you suggested resulted in Hello appearing in the text box. 
 And Hello was picked up in the C# code. Did you forget to add the new code for the last suggestion?  Both of those line are the same

Comment: @Perry, they are not the same.  Look inside the inner brackets.

Comment: Thanks @ w0051977 after more review it appears none of the fields are being read.  The drop down and checkbox were being set back to their default values.  I believe it is a post back issue and have found I did not have an update panel in the code.  Trying to figure out where to put the update panel.  The app uses a master page with 2 other master pages nested so I am having some problems figuring out where to put the update panel.  Have tried adding it to my webpage but just can't get it to work.  Will try getting it added to the master page.